# (GAE, Python) How to read and update a property value as an atomic action?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I want to read a particular property value and update it accordingly. The requirement is that if two or more processes attempt to update the same value, only one of them should succeed and the other should fail because once the property value has been changed, the basis on which the 2nd process attempted to also update the property value is now stale.

E.g., setting property "status" to the value "True" iff it is "False". Now, if both processes initially read "False", and then first one changes it to "True", then 2nd process should re-read the property value instead of also updating it to "True" or just "block" until the previous read-write completes. (In our application, the write immediately follows the read and hence need this to be an atomic operation.)

Developing in Python 2.5 and using db.Model.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to do read+write in a transaction.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/transactions